# JFreechart XYAreaChart changing color

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have an area chart , I want to color the area of the chart which is >0 in green and the area which is <0 in red. I tried the `SetSeriesPaint()` method but it makes all the area chart colored by one color. How to do this?

Here's my code:

```
final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Data");

XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);


JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart("Fun Meter", "", "",
        dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);


// jframe=new ChartFrame("Fun Meter", chart);

ChartPanel CP = new ChartPanel(chart);

XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();



xyPlot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);

xyPlot.setForegroundAlpha(0.75f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `XYDifferenceRenderer`:

```java
XYDifferenceRenderer r = new XYDifferenceRenderer(Color.green,Color.red, false);
plot.setRenderer(r);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you know how to change the color of the border line(or shapes) with the same color of the area?

Comment: @user2928578 `setSeriesPaint`,`setSeriesShape` shape visability is set in the constructor